# odd things happening when capturing mouse drag event JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, event-handling, jquery-events

To capture a mouse drag event I tried putting a mouse up handler within a mouse down handler, so the mouse up would have to be detectable after a mouse down, I was planning on eventually moving an `onmousemove` into the function but I can't get this much to work.

What is happening is that it'll log more and more numbers (at least it seems so) as opposed the four I try to get it to log.

```
var clickx;         
var clicky;         
var releasex;
var releasey;
$('#tdw-layout-editable').bind("mousedown", function(e){
  clickx=e.clientX;
  clicky=e.clientY;
  console.log(clickx + " " + clicky);
  $('#tdw-layout-editable').bind("mouseup", function(f){
     releasex = e.clientX;
     releasey = e.clientY;
     console.log(releasex + " " + releasey);
 });
});
```

Really is bizarre :\

Comment: Have you tried putting the `mouseup` bind outside the `mousedown` bind?

Comment: Dragging is one of the many things that can happen, if I do that I don't think there is a way of explicitly telling that the user is dragging? Or ..wait.. hmm......

...hmmm... you might be right.

Comment: You can tell if the user is dragging by the use of `.mousedown()` and `.mouseup()`. If `mousedown` is executed and `mouseup` isn't and the values of `clientX` and `clientY` changes, then the user is probably dragging.

Comment: Ah was that and I used e in both. Stupid stupid me. Thank you!!

Comment: Yeah, `e` should be `f` in `mouseup`. But I think `mouseup` bind should be outside the `mousedown` bind, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
$(function(){
    var clickx;         
    var clicky;         
    var releasex;
    var releasey;
    $('#tdw-layout-editable').bind("mousedown", function(e){
        clickx=e.clientX;
        clicky=e.clientY;
        console.log(clickx + " " + clicky);
    }).bind("mouseup", function(f){
        releasex = f.clientX;
        releasey = f.clientY;
        console.log(releasex + " " + releasey);
    });  
 });
```